# JavaFX SceneBuilder crashes when fit to parent on mac

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, crash, scenebuilder, macos-sierra

I am using Intellij IDEA (newest version) with SceneBuilder. When i try to use the function "Fit To Parent" in Scenebuilder, it crashes. I have no idea why it does this. Does anybody have a fix for it?

I'm running under macOS Sierra.

Comment: I also use Intellij idea latest on mac os sierra but i haven't used integrated scene builder as it seems slow to me than separate gluon scene builder software . but what do u mean by `fit to parent`?

Comment: i am also using the gluon version. For instance, when i add a split view to an anchor pane, and right click on the split pane, i choose "fit to parent" and it crashes

Comment: Hi again @henrikbossart i did same just now and it didn't crash in my case may be because i have 8gb of ram and idea consumes lots of ram ! Try reinstalling idea IDE or download scene builder.dmg and use that separately to customise fxml file

Comment: Yeah but this IDE hangs a lot when used with scene builder Better use eclipse!